# How to interpret non-significant Dunnett test?

Tags: anova, post-hoc

I am doing a research where the dependent variable is nominal (composed of 5 groups). Four of these groups were experimentally manipulated and the last one is a control.

I carried out a Dunnett test in order to see if my control group were different from the others. However, the result is not significant.

My question is: how do I interpret such result? Does this mean that my control group is not a reliable for comparison? Should I continue to compare my result with this group or should it be discarded and I only work with the four other groups instead (that are different from one another)?

Thank you for your answer!

Aure